# Midi device on OSX with javax.sound.midi

Tags: java, midi

I'm trying to create a simple virtual midi device using javax.sound.midi. I want it to show up in MIDI Studio and appear to other programs which consume midi. However, I can't seem to figure it out. I've got code which can send midi to the IAC driver, but nothing shows up as an independent midi app in MIDI Studio. Is there a particular class I need to instantiate or register it somewhere or some such?

Comment: Are you sure that your JVM (whatever it is) actually supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javax.sound.midi cant create devices. Use the IAC to create a new midi port and all your midi apps should be able to see it an communicate with it. Including your java app.

To create a new port with the IAC go to the finder and look for Audio MIDI Setup. In Audio MIDI Setup on the top menu click on "Window" and then on "Show MIDI Window". Double click on the "IAC Driver" icon and you can create the ports you need.